# How can I set null as default value in Slider from Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm checking the documentation and looks like `Slider` requires the values to be an integer and also fallback to the first or the last item in case I pass a number that is not in the list of values for the Slider.

I'm creating a component that asks the user to select one of these:

```
Never | Rarely | Sometimes | Frequently | Almost always | Always
```

But it doesn't make sense to me to have an initial one selected. The options should show up initially as none of them selected. Is this something that `Slider` was not created to do? Looks so simple not having a value as default. Am I missing something?

Material UI Slider docs: https://material-ui.com/api/slider/

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it is not possible to have MuiSlider without value. It will pick value from `defaultValue` or `value`.

For your use case, in case you need to use Slider component, you need to introduce one more extra value (only for UI sake)

```
import { Typography, Slider } from "@material-ui/core";

const marks = [
  { label: "None", value: 0 },
  {
    label: "Never",
    value: 1
  },
  {
    label: "Rarely Sometimes",
    value: 2
  },
  {
    label: " Frequently",
    value: 3
  },
  {
    label: "Almost always",
    value: 4
  },
  {
    label: "Always",
    value: 5
  }
];


export default function DiscreteSlider() {

  const [sliderValue, setSliderValue] = useState(marks[0].value);

  const onSliderValueChange = (e, val) => {
    setSliderValue(val);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Typography id="discrete-slider" gutterBottom>
        Slider
      </Typography>
      <Slider
        aria-labelledby="discrete-slider"
        valueLabelDisplay="off"
        value={sliderValue}
        onChangeCommitted={onSliderValueChange}
        marks={marks}
        min={0}
        max={5}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

Else you can also check for `Rating` component available in lab version and map its rating with your selection values.

```
import Rating from "@material-ui/lab/Rating";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

export default function SimpleRating() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <Rating
        name="simple-controlled"
        value={value}
        onChange={(event, newValue) => {
          setValue(newValue);
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```